# Django class based views - Filter queryset and save it

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-queryset

I have two Models named Sponsor and Event and they are something like that:

```
class Sponsor(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


class Event(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sponsor = models.ForeignKey(Sponsor)
```

Then, I'm using class based views to Update my Object, and is something like that:

```
class EventUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Event
    form_class = EventForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard_events')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(EventUpdate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

Everything is fine so far! If I don't change my EventForm, my UpdateView works pretty well. The only problem is that I have to change my Form and filter my "sponsor" queryset before render it! That's because the user only can see the "sponsors" that he has created.

So, that's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):    
...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choices = Sponsor.objects.filter(user=self.user).values_list('pk', 'name')
        self.fields['sponsor'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

My view is redering right, only sponsors that the user has created, BUT, when I try to save, I get this error:

> "Cannot assign "u'2'": "Event.sponsor" must be a "Sponsor" instance."

What should I do? I have no clue how to solve this... Am I following the right logic here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Try something like this:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):    
...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sponsor'].queryset = Sponsor.objects.filter(user=self.user)
```